# Updating Profile with react firebase hooks is not showing displayName instantly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, firebase-authentication

I am using react firebase hooks for a react js project and I am trying to update the display name while registering to the website but the displayName does not show instantly.Only After reloading the page the display name is shown.

```js
    const onSubmit = async (data) => {
        console.log("RESULT", data);
        const name = data.Name;
        const email = data.Email;
        const password = data.Password;
        const confirmPassword = data.confirmPassword;
        console.log(name, email, password, confirmPassword);

        if (password !== confirmPassword) {
            setInputError('Passwords do not match');
            return;
        }
        await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        await updateProfile({ displayName: name });
    };
```